# For Loop in a Page Object Not Running Properly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, protractor, pageobjects

I am trying to check for the presence of a modal. If the modal is not present then it will place the value of the timer into browser.sleep(). This will give time for the modal to appear. I am having an issue with a for loop in a page object.  When I run the code below I do not receive the alert and console.log messages under the if when I force a failure by getting changing the object. Also, I do not receive the Timer expired message.

from page_object file  (relevant code)

```
editVinModal: { get: function () {
    return browser.element({id: 'editableVINPart'});
}},
```

---

```
doEditVIN: { value: function () {
    modalFailedToAppear = true;
    console.log('In doEditVIN');

    for(modal_timer = 0 ; modal_timer <= 30; modal_timer++) {

       if (!(this.editVinModal)) {
            alert('In If');
            console.log('Modal failed to appear');
           console.log('Under if - modalFailedToAppear: ', modalFailedToAppear);
            browser.sleep(modal_timer);
           console.log('under if - modal_timer: ',modal_timer);
       }
  else {
            console.log('In else  if else loop');
            //  console.log(browser.isElementPresent(this.editVinModal));
           console.log('modalFailedToAppear: ',modalFailedToAppear);
            modalFailedToAppear = false;
           console.log('modalFailedToAppear: ',modalFailedToAppear);
           console.log('modal_timer: ',modal_timer);
           break;
        }
    }
    if (modalFailedToAppear){
        console.log("Modal is not present within the given time period. Timer has expired.");
    }
    this.editVinLink.click();

    }},
```

Thanks in advance for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're new around here. Welcome!

`browser.sleep()`, generally speaking, does not belong in your Protractor tests (except for debugging purposes). That's the bad news. The good news is that Protractor actually provides a function that does exactly (I think) what you're trying to do. It's called [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and it works like this:

```
browser.wait( function() {  
  return element(by.id('editableVINpart')).isPresent().then( function(present) { 
    return present;
  });
}, 5000)
.then(function() { 
  element(by.id('editableVINpart')).click();
}, function() { 
  console.log('Element not found. :( ');
});
```

`browser.wait()` takes two arguments: first, an anonymous function, which it will execute repeatedly until it returns `true`; second, an amount of time to wait in milliseconds (by the way, `browser.sleep()` also takes a millisecond wait time, so your `for` loop is only waiting 465 milliseconds if it iterates all the way through, or about a half second--not very long).

Then, since `browser.wait()` returns a promise, just like all Protractor functions, we can attach a `.then()` statement to the end of it, which will execute the first passed-in function if the promise is successful, or the second passed-in function if it is not.

If you often have to wait for an element to be present (and for some reason it isn't synchronized with the Angular page load), it may be useful to you to have a reusable form of the function, like this:

```
var waitThenClick = function(el) {
  browser.wait( function() {
    return el.isPresent().then( function(present) { 
       return present;
    });
  }, 5000)
  .then(function() { 
    el.click();
  }, function() { 
    console.log('Element with locator: ' + el.locator + ' was not found. :( ');
  });
};
```

Then you could just call it like this, for whatever element you need:

```
waitThenClick(element(by.id('editableVINpart')));
```

Good luck! Make sure to get good and clever with asynchronous stuff (especially promises) with problems like this. Protractor promises trip up the best of us.

Comment: Great answer! We can also make a custom expected condition here.

Comment: You're right; it would be fairly easy to pass in an expected condition as well as a custom wait time, a custom behavior, and so forth. To be honest, though, I'm a little worried about making the function spec look too much like the function. I assume @llacey knows more about how flexible the function would need to be than I do.

Comment: I agree, basically the function inside the browser.wait that you've provided is already an "expected condition". Thanks.

Comment: Isaac Lyman, Thanks very much !!  It worked like a charm !  You are correct I am new to posting on Stackoverflow and I am new to Protractor, Angular, Jasmine, and Selenium.  Some of it is easy and some are not like Promises.  I understand it conceptually but, the usage is a little shaky.  Thanks, again.  This newby appreciates your help.   - Lyle Lacey

Comment: I've gone through a lot of the same learning curves lately; feel free to let me know if you have any more questions on the subject.

Comment: Issac, Thanks, I will.  I will try not to be a pest. :)